# Matrix representation and permutation matrices

Tags: matrices, representation-theory

In order to find the matrix representation associated to a permutation representation I identify each permutation with the corrisponding matrix representation.

How can I prove that these matrices satisfy the relations of homomorphism?

Given two permutation $\pi$ and $\sigma$, if ${P}_{\pi}$ and ${P}_{\sigma}$ are the corrisponding permutation matrices, I have: ${P}_{\sigma}{P}_{\pi}={P}_{\pi\circ\sigma}$.

But, in order to have an homomorphism, shouldn't I have  ${P}_{\sigma}{P}_{\pi}={P}_{\sigma\circ\pi}$?

Thanks!

Comment: Replace the matrices by their transposed ones.

Comment: @Nimda So, in order to have an homomorphism, have I to associate to each permutation the trasposed of the corresponding matrix permutation? Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, this is due to the fact that the notation for a permutation can be quite ambiguous. Let a permutation map the set of numbers $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to $\{1,3,5,2,4\}$. One can say that $3$ has taken the place of $2$. $2$ has taken the place of $4$ and $4$ has taken the place of $5$, $5$ has taken the place of $3$ so the permutation is $(3,2,4,5)$. On the other hand we can say $2$ is mapped to $3$, $3$ maps to $5$ etc. so the permutation is $(2,3,5,4)$.